# WordPress Custom Admin Menu with Submenus

Tags: php, wordpress-theming, wordpress

Im have been looking all morning at the WP Codex as well as forum post around the web and the ones on Stackoverflow with no luck so far.
I am trying to make a top level menu with a submenu, i have been able to get it working up to the top level menu but not the sub menu and now im getting stuck with either insufficient privileges or a wall of php errors.

Link to screenshot of php errors: http://prntscr.com/8f2pvw

Functions.php Code

```
defined( 'ABSPATH' ) or die( 'No script kiddies please!' );

/* ADDING FUNCIONALITY
============================== */

// Enqueues Javascript / CSS Files
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'my_enqueued_assets' );

function my_enqueued_assets() {
wp_enqueue_script( 'dragoncove-js', plugin_dir_url( __FILE__ ) . '/js/dragoncove.js', array( 'jquery' ), '1.0', true );
wp_enqueue_script( 'dragoncove-css', plugin_dir_url( __FILE__ ) . '/css/dragoncove.css', array( 'stylesheet' ), '1.0', true );
}

/* ADDING THE ADMIN MENU 
======================================== */

// NEW MENU TEST
add_action( 'admin_menu', 'dragoncove_adminmenu' );

function dragoncove_adminmenu() {
add_menu_page( 'dragoncove_adminmenu', 'Dragon Cove', 'manage_options', 'dragoncove/dragoncove.php', '', plugins_url( 'dragoncove/images/icon.png' ), 100 );
add_submenu_page( 'dragoncove_adminmenu', 'Font Awesome Page', 'Font Awesome Page', 'manage_options', 'fontawesomemenu_page', 'fontawesomemenu_page_callback' );
}

// Admin Page
function dragoncove_adminmenu_page(){

if ( !current_user_can( 'manage_options' ) )  {
    wp_die( __( 'You do not have sufficient permissions to access this page.' ) );
}

echo '<div class="wrap">';
echo '<h2>Dragon Cove Admin Page</h2>';
echo '<form>

        <div class="row">

            <div class="large-12">
                <input type="text" name="news" value="news_update" placeholder="news update" />
            </div>
        </div>

    </form>';
echo '</div>';

}

// Font Awesome Page
function dragoncove_fontawesomemenu_page(){

echo '<div class="wrap">';
echo '<h2>Dragon Cove Sub Page</h2>';
echo '<form>

        <div class="row">

            <div class="large-12">
                <p>Something will probably go here one day</p>
            </div>
        </div>

    </form>';
echo '</div>';

}

// Font Awesome Page Callback
function fontawesomemenu_page_callback() {

echo '<div class="wrap"><div id="icon-tools" class="icon32"></div>';
    echo '<h2>My Custom Submenu Page</h2>';
echo '</div>';

}

?>
```

Comment: The "cannot redeclare function" error is pretty self explaining.

Comment: except that that's the first and only time its being called, what other place am i remotely referencing that?

Comment: The error message tells you exactly in which plugin a function with the same name is defined. Just rename it in your theme.

Comment: the issue was this parameter:' dragoncove/dragoncove.php' under the add_menu_page

Answer (score 0):

Was an issue with parameters, fixed now. below is the code if anyone else wanted it.
edit: just cleaned it up a little.

```
defined( 'ABSPATH' ) or die( 'No script kiddies please!' );

/* ADDING FUNCIONALITY
====================================== */

// Enqueues Javascript / CSS Files
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'my_enqueued_assets' );

function my_enqueued_assets() {
wp_enqueue_script( 'dragoncove-js', plugin_dir_url( __FILE__ ) . '/js/dragoncove.js', array( 'jquery' ), '1.0', true );
wp_enqueue_script( 'dragoncove-css', plugin_dir_url( __FILE__ ) . '/css/dragoncove.css', array( 'stylesheet' ), '1.0', true );
}

/* ADDING THE ADMIN MENU
============================ */

// NEW MENU TEST
add_action( 'admin_menu', 'dragoncove_menu' );

function dragoncove_menu() {
add_menu_page( 'dragoncove_adminmenu', 'Dragon Cove', 'manage_options', 'dragoncove_adminmenu_page', 'dragoncove_page', plugins_url( 'dragoncove/images/icon.png' ), 100 );
add_submenu_page( 'dragoncove_adminmenu_page', 'Font Awesome Page', 'Font Awesome Page', 'manage_options', 'fontawesomemenu_page', 'fontawesomemenu_page' );
}

/* Admin Page */
function dragoncove_page() {

if ( !current_user_can( 'manage_options' ) )  {
    wp_die( __( 'You do not have sufficient permissions to access this page.' ) );
}
echo '<div class="wrap">';
echo '<h2>Dragon Cove Plugin</h2>';
echo '<p>Here is where the form would go if I actually had options.</p>';
echo '<form>

        <div class="row">

            <div class="large-12">
                <input type="text" name="news" value="news_update" placeholder="news update" />
            </div>
        </div>

    </form>';
echo '</div>';
}

// Font Awesome Page
function fontawesomemenu_page() {

echo '<div class="wrap"><div id="icon-tools" class="icon32"></div>';
    echo '<h2>My Custom Submenu Page</h2>';
echo '</div>';

}
```